# ZEEP WSDL LookupError: No type 'string' in namespace

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I'm trying to use ZEEP v1.2.0 to connect to some service and ran into this issue.

I just execute: `python -mzeep http://fulfill.sfcservice.com/default/svc/wsdl`

Result:

`zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No type 'string' in namespace
http://www.chinafulfill.com/CffSvc/. Available types are: [...]`

Am I missing anything here to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is a bug in the WSDL file, It defines an element with type "tns:string", I assume they meant "xsd:string".

See the following line in the wsdl:

Comment: spotted 4 lines using tns instead of xsd. Thanks!